# Login via AJAX not working though code seems good - getting crazy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I have done several attemps to login with the traditional ajax call. I am possibly missing something and every time I press the button, I always end up in the ajax->success wrong part of the code alert('out).

What I want afterall, is that in case the of success it redirects me to the intro page and if not, it displays the error in a certain area (in this case I am just making an alert to see if I get it right. However, it always goes to this part and gives me an alert of the redirect full page...)

JS CODE

```
    $(function() {

         var options = { 

            beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
            url: 'http://localhost/dh/login.php',
            success: function(data) 
            {
                if (data == 'correct') {

                    alert('in');
                    window.location.href = 'http://localhost/dh/main2.php';
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert('out');
                    alert(data);
                }


            },
            error: function()
            {

            },
            complete: function() 
            {

            },


        }; 

       $("#sign_in_other").ajaxForm(options);

       function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
              var queryString = $.param(formData);
              alert('BeforeSend method: \n\nAbout to submit: \n\n' + queryString);
              return true;
            }

        function resetForm($form) {
            $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
            $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
                 .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');

        }

    });
```

PHP Code

```
    <?php

        include 'core/init.php';
        //logged_in_redirect();



        $username = '';
        $password = '';


        if (empty($_POST) === false) 
        {
            $username = trim($_POST['username']);
            $password = trim($_POST['password']);

            if (empty($username) || empty($password)) 
            {
                //$errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password';
                array_push($errors, "You need to enter a username and password");
            } 
            if (user_exists($username) === false) 
            {
                //$errors[] = 'We cant find that username, have you regitered?';
                array_push($errors, "We cant find that username, have you regitered?"); 
            } 

            $login = login($username, $password);

            if ($login === false) 
            {
                //$errors[] = 'This username and password is incorrect';
                array_push($errors, "This username and password is incorrect");
            }


            if (is_int($login))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                echo 'correct';
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo output_errors($errors);
            }



            if (count($errors) == 0) {
                array_push($errors, "No errors were found. Thanks!");
            }


        } 


    ?>
```

HTML code

```
       <form  id="sign_in_other" method="POST" action="http://localhost/dh/login.php" class="">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <!--<label for="username">Username</label>-->
                  <input type="text" class="input-registration-form" name="username" id="set-round-first" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <!--<label for="password">Password</label>-->
                  <input type="password" class="input-registration-form" name="password" id="set-round-last" placeholder="Password">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" name="signin" id="btn-registrarion-form" class="btn btn-info btn-registrarion-form">Sign in</button>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: Is it a server side or client side issue? I mean, what data is returned by server, "correct" ?

Comment: it never returns the 'correct'. Instead it always enters the 'else statement' displaying the alert('out') followed by an empty error table. I removed the script so I could echo everything that comes from the php file. It never returns the 'correct'. Not sure why.

Comment: But then what output `alert(data)` ??? You should be able to debug it server side and see which not expected result you get. For example, is `$_POST['username']` what you expect it to be? Etc...

Comment: Yes, I tested it. Using the beforeSubmit option in the AJAX call, I can see what goes/ is submitted to the php file and so on

Comment: But what output alert(data) ??? Have you tested $_POST['username'] ??? I'm not talking about beforeSubmit option which seems quite irrelevant regarding your issue

Comment: data in this case will be either a string 'correct' which in that case redirects me to the desired page, or the error resulting from not complying with any of the rules.

Comment: I just tested again and it sends me the echo 'correct' though when getting into the ajax success function, it enters the alert('out') followed by the alert(data) = 'correct'. I wonder: if data ='correct', why does it never enters the first if rule?

Comment: Damn, i was thinking you still didn't understand my question... We are safe now... So, your server returns 'correct' but `if (data == 'correct')` is not reached. Try to trim data but i don't see any reason in your posted code, maybe you forget to post some relevant code: `if ($.trim(data) === 'correct')`

Comment: the problem is in the AJAX success IF statement. It never gets TRUE to data = 'correct'. I don't know why...

Comment: DAmmmm man...you were totally right. It works now. It was the TRIM.